# Add some content after installing plugin in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, plugins

I want to open a browser window with plugin info after plugin installed successfully in Eclipse before re-starting the Eclipse. How to do it?

Comment: Is this off-topic? I feel like it is, but at the same time not.

Comment: I have to display a webpage after installing the plugin in eclipse and before restarting the eclipse.which extension I can use??